# SQL [Error]: There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 44,Token in error = - ]

Tags: c#, sql-server

I can't seem to figure out why this statement is giving me problems:

```
sqlCommand.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Fulfilled_Shipments_Data (amazon-order-id) VALUES " + lines[0];
```

I am getting error:

```
[Error]: There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 44,Token in error = - ]
```

which points to the - in amazon-order-id.

I get the same error when I execute the SQL from within visual studio, however I can query existing data using that column name.

I am sure this is a trivial matter for a SQL guru, but I am scratching my head so any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: Might want to try `VALUES ( " + lines[0] + " )"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape `amazon-order-id` because it has minus(dash) sign. It should be `[amazon-order-id]`:

```
...INSERT INTO Fulfilled_Shipments_Data ([amazon-order-id])...
```

Also, values should be in parenthesis :`VALUES (" + lines[0]+")";`

Final version:

```
sqlCommand.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO 
Fulfilled_Shipments_Data ([amazon-order-id])
VALUES (" + lines[0]+")";
```

Comment: That works for the first error, however the data contained in lines[0] contains dashes as well. I have tried escaping it via the same method but get an error:  The column name is not valid. [ Node name (if any) = ,Column name = S01-8XXXXXX-XXXXXXX

Comment: [] are used to escape column names. if lines[0] is a string, you should put it in single quotes : `...VALUES('" + lines[0]+"')"`. You also have to make sure `lines[0]` doesn't have any special characters and escape if needed

Comment: Instead of putting value directly in the query, use parameters (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) . This way you don't have to escape values manually.

Comment: Thank you, the string literal did it for me

Answer (score 2):

I think your SQL syntax should look like this:

```
sqlCommand.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Fulfilled_Shipments_Data (amazon-order-id) VALUES ('" + lines[0] + "')";
```

OR

```
sqlCommand.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Fulfilled_Shipments_Data (amazon-order-id) VALUES (" + lines[0] + ")";
```

depending on the data type of `amazon-order-id`

Answer (score 1):

try these .

```
sqlCommand.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Fulfilled_Shipments_Data (amazon-order-id) VALUES ('" + lines[0]+"')";
```

OR

```
sqlCommand.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Fulfilled_Shipments_Data ([amazon-order-id]) VALUES ('" + lines[0]+"')";
```