# DML query execution from datagridview to SSCE

Tags: c#, datagridview, sql-server-ce, dml

**What I am trying to do:**

Execute DML statements into database (`SSCE`) using `Datagridview` and command buttons.

**The Problem:**

I am getting exact same error as this post: [SQL [Error]: There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 44,Token in error = - ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875570/sql-error-there-was-an-error-parsing-the-query-token-line-number-1-token)

Based on those answers and others available on the web, I have validated the query string, yet not able to solve it. There's also one other aspect I have doubts.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SqlCeConnection CONN = new SqlCeConnection("Data 
                                          Source=LocalDBSSCompactEdition.sdf;"))
            {
                SqlCeCommand comm = new SqlCeCommand();
                comm.Connection = CONN;
                CONN.Open();
                int i = dataGridView2.Rows.Count-1;

                    String queryString = @"INSERT INTO tblEmployee VALUES ("
                    + dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["E_ID"].Value + ", "
                    + dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["FirstName"].Value + ", "
                    + dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["LastName"].Value + ", "
                    + dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["DeptID"].Value + ");";
                    comm.CommandText = queryString;
                    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }
```

1) `E_ID` column is `IDENTITY`(auto-increment). However I got an error, saying that I must include all the columns in DataGridview to match to the database table. Could this be the issue that I am getting or could it be my syntax?

2) I want to insert new rows/updates/deleted rows from Datagridview to the database table using a button click event. Is this the efficient way of doing so?

Some insights to the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it solved. I don't believe in answering my own-question. Just added the answer hoping for someone else's reference in the future.

1) `i` variable was referring to an empty row in the `datagridview`...Hence the values to be inserted were null and these columns are specified `NOT NULL`...

2) First rule was to follow the usual `INSERT` statement when ID column is auto-increment. So I specify the columns that I want to insert data for.

3) The data that I was entering were not quoted to treat as `String`. Fixed.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SqlCeConnection CONN = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=LocalDBSSCompactEdition.sdf;"))
            {
                CONN.Open();
                SqlCeCommand comm = CONN.CreateCommand();                
                int i = dataGridView2.Rows.Count-1;

                    String queryString = @"INSERT INTO tblEmployee (FirstName, LastName, DeptID) VALUES ('"                    
                    + dataGridView2.Rows[5].Cells["FirstName"].Value + "','"
                    + dataGridView2.Rows[5].Cells["LastName"].Value + "',"
                     + dataGridView2.Rows[5].Cells["DeptID"].Value + ");";
                    comm.CommandText = queryString;
                    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    CONN.Close();    
            }
        }
```